# How to hide Add new Term area for taxonomy terms for specific role (Client)

Tags: user-roles

I have a taxonomy "page type" i want to hide the "Add New Page Type" side for the user with role Client actually i want that user with role client won't be able to add new terms,
Please check the screenshot here https://prnt.sc/vi2qg0
i tried the user edit role plugin but that completely hide taxonomy for the user with role client
screenshot here https://prnt.sc/vi2rox and here result in https://prnt.sc/vi2smd completely hide page type taxonomy and actually i want only "Add New Page Type"

let me know if need more explanation, thanks.

Comment: i have done that like this 

`function hd_add_buttons() {
       global $pagenow;
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 if ( in_array( 'client', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
  //The user has the "client" role
echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".post-type-page #col-left .form-wrap").remove();});</script>';
 }
}
add_action('admin_head','hd_add_buttons');`

is this good?

Comment: You could try to add the Role name as class to the body of dashboard and then hide via CSS using for example, White label CMS or by adding CSS to the dashboard programatically. to add the role class try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984332/wordpress-add-user-role-on-body-class , but the previous solution also could be also combined with my approach, without touching functions.php you could re-use the jquery code of Jamil and paste in the white label cms js field...

Comment: Got it, Thanks A lot